# How to cache/target tasks with the same name in a Flow with prefect?

Tags: python, prefect

I am trying to find a `target` pattern or cache config to differentiate between tasks with the same name in a flow.

[image]

As highlighted from the diagram above only one of the tasks gets cached and the other get overwritten. I tried using `task-slug` but to no avail.

```
@task(
    name="process_resource-{task_slug}",
    log_stdout=True,
    target=task_target
    )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to format the task name instead of the target. (task names are not template-able strings).

The following snippet is probably what you want:

```py
@task(name="process_resource", log_stdout=True, target="{task_name}-{task_slug}")
```

Comment: @Josh-The target is a template with `task_full_name` ... so I thought I could pass the `name` (slug) and the target would pick up the new name.

Answer (score 1):

After further research it looks like the [documentation](https://docs.prefect.io/core/advanced_tutorials/task-guide.html#adding-tasks-to-flows) directly addresses changing task configuration on the fly - Without breaking target location templates.

```
@task
def number_task():
    return 42

with Flow("example-v3") as f:
    result = number_task(task_args={"name": "new-name"})

print(f.tasks) # {<Task: new-name>}
```